# Saxon HE XQuery process nodes in document throwing error about BaseUri

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xquery, saxon

I am trying to use Saxon HE from C# and the XQuery processor to process an input XML document as follows (input document is `req.XML` and XQuery string is `req.XQuery`):

```
        Processor processor = new Processor();

        var documentBuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
        documentBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("file://");
        var xdmNode = documentBuilder.Build(new StringReader(req.XML));

        XQueryCompiler compiler = processor.NewXQueryCompiler();
        compiler.BaseUri = "file:///C:/temp/";
        compiler.DeclareNamespace("saxon", "http://saxon.sf.net/");
        XQueryExecutable exp = compiler.Compile(req.XQuery);
        XQueryEvaluator eval = exp.Load();

        eval.ContextItem = xdmNode;

        var results = new XdmDestination();

        eval.Run(results);


        XmlXQueryResponse output = new XmlXQueryResponse();

        output.XMLResult = results.XdmNode.OuterXml;
```

And here is the XQuery query I am testing with:

```
for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by $x/title
return $x/title
```

And here is the XML file I am testing with: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> Saxon.Api.DynamicError: 'Exception thrown by URIResolver'

This error is thrown by the line `eval.Run(results)`.

If I remove the line `compiler.BaseUri = "file:///C:/temp/";` I get the same error.

I struggling to understand why it is complaining about BaseUri, since I am new to Saxon HE.

Any idea why this might be happening?  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us a minimal but complete sample to allow us to reproduce the problem? How does the Xquery code look, how the input string?

Comment: Read following : https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/dotnet/xmlparsing.html

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for replying.  I added this information - the XQuery and the input XML string into the question.

Comment: Where have you placed the file `books.xml`? Why do you try to set `ContextItem` but in the XQuery use no context item `.` or why don't you simply use the path `for $x in /bookstore/book`? I think you get the error as `doc("books.xml")` fails. Of course if you want to load the file directly from the server then you can just use `doc('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to load the file from the server use

```
for $x in doc("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>30
order by $x/title
return $x/title
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEM

For your query, if you parse the XML yourself with DocumentBuilder and set it as the context item, you can just use `for $x in /bookstore/book`, you don't need the `doc` function call.

Answer (score 0):

If the file actually exists at `file:///C:/temp/books.xml` then I would expect your code to succeed.

If the file doesn't exist at that location, then I would expect a different error: an FODC0005 or FODC0002 that clearly tells you the file is not found.

If the location `file:///C:/temp/` doesn't exist, then I can see things getting more confused; perhaps we should be producing better diagnostics in this case.

However, you haven't given enough information for us to tell which of these cases applies.